# how to post multiple values from drop down

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have a html form with multiple choice for values. When i post the values the values must be stored in the database table under the column as text separated by a comma. But it throws an error as below.
Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '1','Mobile hardware, Android','Android SDK', 'Hindi','Yes','Yes','', '1234')' at line 2

My HTML:

```
  <label for="cc">Any 2 Certification courses</label>
   <input name="cc" type="text" placeholder="course1,course2">
       <br>

                         <label for="pls">Programming Language Skills</label>
                            <select multiple name="pls" class="pure-input-1-2">
                                <option>C</option>
                                <option>C++</option>
                                <option>Java</option>
                                <option>HTML</option>
                                <option>Javascript</option>
                                <option>CSS</option>
                                <option>PHP</option>
                                <option>SQL</option>
                                <option>.NET</option>
                                <option>Android SDK</option>
                                <option>others</option>
                            </select>   
        <br>
```

my php script:

```
 $pls = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['pls']);// here pls(prog lang skills) is a column in table with the type text, do i have to make it a varchar? 

$sql="INSERT INTO $tbl_name (name, regno,email,phone,dept,yop,gender,ten,twelve,diploma,cgpa,soa,hoa,cc,pls,cls,night,bpo,marketing,password)
VALUES('$name','$regno','$email','$phone','$dept','$yop','$gender','$ten','$twelve','$diploma','$cgpa','$soa',''$hoa','$cc','$pls',
'$cls','$night','$bpo','$marketing', '$password')";
```

Comment: Have you tried to `var_dump` your `$_POST['pls']` to see what it returns? It returns an array.

Comment: can u add / show your query

Comment: @NaveenThally have added my query too

Comment: @N0062eclipse ''$hoa' one quote extra and also <option value=''> missing whether you are able to get the values

Answer (score 2):

You need to loop the array returned by `$_POST['pls']` using `foreach()` like

```
$str = '';
foreach($_POST['pls'] as $vals) {
    $str .= $vals . ' ';
}

$newstr = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $str);
echo rtrim($newstr, ' '); //strips out last space
```

Or strip out the space before you use `mysqli_real_escape_string()`

Comment: does this mean i have to change my column name in database as "str"? I mean how does it get stored into the table?

Comment: @N0062eclipse `$str` is a variable, you can keep whatever you want to, and the `$newstr` holds the concatenated string, you can also use a `,` instead of space...

Comment: the column name and variable name that goes into that column are same. "pls". so just store in a temporary "newstr" and while i use INSERT INTO $tblname(pls) VALUES('$newstr')

Comment: @N0062eclipse yea, exactly,try it out, also make sure you trim out the last space using `rtrim` before you save to the db

Comment: I tried with a single value and database was successfully updated, did not use pls[] ie, as array. but problematic fields are left blank in the database table

Comment: @N0062eclipse I dont see how that won't work for you, whats the datatype of your column?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58958/discussion-between-n0062eclipse-and-mr-alien).

Answer (score 2):

Your select name should resemble an array in PHP to access multiple values, change your select name as follow:

```
<select multiple name="pls[]" class="pure-input-1-2">
```

otherwise you will get only one value.

Comment: aaah I missed that part

Comment: need i add "pls[]" if i intent to send add input box where user enters values separated by comma?

Comment: i tried with a single value and database was successfully updated, did not use pls[] ie, as array.

Comment: If users seperate values by comma in a single input box, you don't need to use [] to make an array. You use it only when you are sending multiple values under the same nam. For example if you have a group of check boxes which are related to one another, then they share the same name and that name will contain [], if they are not related to one another, then their names should be different anyway, and you don't need []. You use [] to send multiple values under the same name. Then php sees that as an array and you can have access to every element using array specific operators, loops, ....